# Replace value comparing range with another range in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in two columns in excel, data in "column a" need to replace with another single value lets say "Newdata" matching data in "column b", for example, **4001024** and **4000521** in column b are also present in column a so I need to replace those values in column a with "newData".

the sample data and output is as bellow. 
I need to look all values of column B as well, column b contains aroudn 1000 entries and column a contains more than 5000 entries

original data        expected output

`column a column b   column a column b
4000520 4001024     4000520 4001024
4000520 4001204     4000520 4001204
4000520 4002475     4000520 4002475
4000521 4002477     newData 4002477
4000521 4002517     newData 4002517
4000521 4003062     newData 4003062
4000521 4000521     newData 4000521
4000521             newData 
4000521             newData 
4000521             newData 
4000522             4000522 
4000522             4000522 
4001024             newData 
4001024             newData`

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain the logic a bit more in detail? in your example table, what exactly are you doing? Also, do you mean columns a and b, instead of cell?

Comment: I have edited the question, can you understand now? thank you in advance

Comment: So any value, that appears in both column a and b, is to be replaced by "newData" in column A. What I still do not understand: Why did 4001024 disappear from column B in the output?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake! actually column b is unchanged in output, yes you are right, any value that appears in both column a and b is to be replaced by "newData" in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VBA, the code could be something like this:

```
Sub newdata()

Dim awb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim a_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column A
Dim b_lastrow As Integer     'last row of column B

    Set awb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = awb.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet

    With ws

        a_lastrow = .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
        b_lastrow = .Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 1 To a_lastrow

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B1:B" & b_lastrow), .Range("A" & r).Value) > 0 Then
                .Range("A" & r).Value = "newData"
            End If

        Next r

    End With

    MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

Post this code into a separate module. Change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a helper column in column C and use this formula in cell C2 and drag it down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B:B,1,FALSE)),A2,"NewData")
```

If the value from column A is found in Column B, then it will be replaced with "NewData", otherwise it will just show up as the original value.

Then you can copy column C and paste values over the original column A.