# Macro: If find specific string in Column B, then replace Column A with a new String

Tags: vba, excel

In Column B, I want to search for "hmc" and then replace its corresponding cell in Column A with the string "Found".

I tried to use the macro recorder to filter Column B for "hmc", and this can be done. But I need to go to Column A and replace the corresponding cell with the string "Found".

```
Col A   Col B
Accept  hmc
123     hmc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
123     hmc
Accept  hmc
```

Would be rewritten to:

```
Col A   Col B
Found   hmc
Found   hmc
Accept  xcc
Accept  xcc
Found   hmc
Found   hmc
```

Comment: define separate range for column A and try to loop with proper index where you want to update the value

Answer (score 0):

check this answer: [StackOverflow - almost same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322648/replace-value-comparing-range-with-another-range-in-excel/37335010#37335010)

You only need to change this part:

```
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("B1:B" & b_lastrow), .Range("A" & r).Value) > 0 Then
    .Range("A" & r).Value = "newData"
 End If
```

to:

```
 If .Range("B" & r).Value = "hmc" Then
    .Range("A" & r).Value = "found"
 End If
```

As for the rest of the code, you need to change the Sheetname to yours, and possibly also the ranges where your data is. This code assumes that it starts in A1.

Comment: sorry i use the codes listed in to but got error. 

 If .Range("B" & r).Value = "hmc" Then
    .Range("A" & r).Value = "found"
 End If
 
End Sub

Comment: i deleted the dot before Range. it gives Method range of object global failed

Comment: pls advise what does & r mean? tq

Comment: understand the code now about the r. but it is hard code the last row as A100000 and B100000, how to make not hard code but rather find the last data as i'm afraid data may exceed the hard coded value. tq

Comment: then add a zero to each. this is not hard coded. it just starts from A100000 and searches upward. change it to A1000000 and try again

Comment: Also, please keep the dot before Range. This is because it is part of a With-Block. So basically it abbreviates ws.Range.